# TYPO3 third navigation level with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typoscript

I have the following typoscript snippet which makes me a drop down navigation with bootstrap.

```
 MENU = HMENU
    MENU.entryLevel = 0
    #NAVIMAIN.excludeUidList = 

    MENU {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1

    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.before = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    IFSUB.after =  <b class="caret"></b></a>
    IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    ACTIFSUB = 1
    ACTIFSUB.before = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    ACTIFSUB.after =  <b class="caret"></b></a>
    ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active">|</li>
    ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
  }

       2 = TMENU
  2 {
    expAll = 1

    ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    ACTIFSUB = 1
    ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = |
    ACTIFSUB.before = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">
    ACTIFSUB.after = </li>
    ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.before = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">
    IFSUB.after = </li>
    IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    SPC = 1
    SPC.allWrap = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">|</li>

    wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
  }
```

How can I add a third level Menü as dropdown of a second level menü?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default navbar of Bootstrap only supports two levels. I'd recommend using [Smartmenus jQuery](https://www.smartmenus.org/) to get three or more sublevels.

The adapted HMENU setup for TYPO3 would be like this:

```
lib.bootstrap3-smartmenus = COA
lib.bootstrap3-smartmenus {
  wrap = <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> <div class="container-fluid"> | </div> </nav>
  
  10 = COA
  10 {
    wrap = <div class="navbar-header"> | </div>
    10 = COA
    10 {
      // hamburger icon:
      wrap = <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> | </button>
      10 = TEXT
      10.value = <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      20 = TEXT
      20.value = <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      21 < .20
      22 < .20
    }
  
    // company name/logo:
    20 = TEXT
    20.value = Project name
    20.typolink {
      parameter = http://www.example.org/
      ATagParams = class="navbar-brand"
    }
  }
  
  20 = COA
  20 {
    wrap = <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"> | </div>
  
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
      wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> | </ul>
  
      1 = TMENU
      1 {
        expAll = 1
  
        NO = 1
        NO {
          ATagTitle.field = title
          wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
  
        CUR < .NO
        CUR {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
 
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
          ATagTitle.field = title
          ATagParams = class="sub-arrow"
          linkWrap = |<span class="caret"></span>
          ATagBeforeWrap = 1
          wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
 
        CURIFSUB < .IFSUB
        CURIFSUB {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
  
        ACT < .CUR
        ACTIFSUB < .CURIFSUB
  
        SPC = 1
        SPC {
          // no divider, if first menu item on this level (using optionSplit):
          wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown-header">|</li> |*| <li class="divider"></li><li class="dropdown-header">|</li>
        }
      }
  
      2 < .1
      2 {
        wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
  
      }
  
      3 < .2
      4 < .3
    }
  }
}
```

Some changes to the markup must be made (e.g. no more `data-toggle="dropdown"`).

In addition to the default Bootstrap files, these CSS and JavaScripts must be used:

- jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.css
- jquery.smartmenus.min.js
- jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min.js

I once created a demo (including this information) [here](http://demo.sklein-medien.de/hmenu/bootstrap3-smartmenus/en/hmenu/home/).

---

**Edit:** If you rather want to extend the default Bootstrap navbar with the provided example, you can use the following TypoScript setup. I successfully tested it with the extra CSS of the Codepen example.

It removes the caret element in sublevels and add the extra classes you need. You can adjust the classes `container`/`container-fluid` and `navbar-fixed-top` to your needs.

This TypoScript (as well as the snippet above) will also take care of menu separator pages in TYPO3 (`SPC`) and adds the divider element of Bootstrap only, if it is not the first subpage of this branch of the page tree.

```
lib.navbar = COA
lib.navbar {
    wrap = <nav class="navbar navbar-default"> <div class="container-fluid"> | </div> </nav>

    10 = COA
    10 {
        wrap = <div class="navbar-header"> | </div>
        10 = COA
        10 {
            // hamburger icon:
            wrap = <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">|</button>
            10 = TEXT
            10.value = <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            20 = TEXT
            20.value = <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            21 < .20
            22 < .20
        }

        // company name/logo:
        20 = TEXT
        20.value = Project name
        20.typolink {
            parameter = http://www.example.org/
            ATagParams = class="navbar-brand"
        }
    }

    20 = HMENU
    20 {
        wrap = <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> | </ul> </div>

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1

            NO = 1
            NO {
                ATagTitle.field = title
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            }

            CUR < .NO
            CUR {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
            }

            ACT < .CUR

            IFSUB = 1
            IFSUB {
                ATagTitle.field = title
                ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                linkWrap = |<b class="caret"></b>
                ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
            }

            ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
            ACTIFSUB {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active">|</li>
            }

            CURIFSUB < .ACTIFSUB
        }

        2 < .1
        2 {
            // Adjust several classes for sublevels
            wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu  multi-level">|</ul>
            IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown-submenu">|</li>
            ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown-submenu active">|</li>
            // Remove caret element (correct arrow is set with ::after pseudo element)
            IFSUB.linkWrap >
            ACTIFSUB.linkWrap >

            CURIFSUB < .ACTIFSUB

            SPC = 1
            SPC {
                // no divider, if first menu item on this level (using optionSplit):
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown-header">|</li> |*| <li class="divider"></li><li class="dropdown-header">|</li>
            }
        }

        3 < .2
        4 < .3
    }
}
```

Please be aware that pages containing sublevels cannot not be linked to a page in TYPO3 this way. You'll need to use *Shortcut* pages, just as do with these pages on the first level of this navigation.

Comment: If I use this example with "plain" bootstrap: https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD?editors=1100 How would the typoscript for this look like?

Comment: Thanks, how can I use My `###Menu###` Marker with your typoscript code

Comment: I assume you already have a [TEMPLATE cObject](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Template/Index.html) in your page. Inside that cObject, you can use a reference to the navigation like `marks.Menu < lib.navbar`. It will then replace ###Menu### in your HTML template with the navigation. Of course it's required to include the navigation somewhere in your TyoScript setup so it can be referenced in the first place.

Comment: If you're still new to TYPO3 and TypoScript, I can recommend the [TypoScript Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Index.html) as well as the advice to use the modern FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject instead of the outdated marker templating. It introduces so-called viewhelpers which make templating quite easier and allows you to split HTML templates into smaller partials. There are several tutorials which can help you with that.

Comment: To clarify my second comment, which is no longer editable: `=<` is the correct operator for **referencing** an object while `<` will **copy** the current state. Background: TypoScript is parsed line by line. Declarations can be overwritten (or deleted) by latter TypoScript.